# How to enable/disable airplane mode?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am trying enable/disable airplane mode programmatically but the following code is not working.The app stops unexpectedly while running and I have to forceclose

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_airplanemode);
```

Code to check the status of airplane mode
        boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
                  getContentResolver(), 
                  Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

Code to toggle

```
    Settings.System.putInt(
              getContentResolver(),
              Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
```

Reloading the intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
        TextView a = new TextView(this);
        a.setText("AIRPLANE MODE : "+isEnabled);
        setContentView(a);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_airplanemode, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Provide stack trace, but most likely you are getting a SecurityException, since you don't have permissions to modify system settings.

Comment: Nikolay Elenov : thank you very much but how do i provide a stack trace...i m new to android and i tried context.getmenuInflater() but it returns "context can't be resolved"

Comment: Connect your phone to USB, run `adb logcat` in a terminal or check the Eclipse logcat view.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the following. Add the following to your Manifesf file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

And use the following lines of code in your onResume(),

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
newIntent.putExtra("state", true);
sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

This should work, do not need to add context.sendBroadcast().

Answer (score 0):

Try to add required permissions to your Androidmanifest.xml file
Try adding

```
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```