# How to programmatically enable airplane mode on Android?

Tags: android, rooted-device, airplane-mode

I'm trying to programmatically enable/disable Airplane mode on Android.

Requested the following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

And using the following code:

```
String[] task = new String[] { "su", "settings put global airplane_mode_on 1", "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true" };
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(task);
  process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
                
}catch (SecurityException e){
                
}catch (Exception e) {
                
}
```

This **works correctly** for **rooted Meizu 5** (Android 6.0).
But it **doesn't work** for **rooted Samsung S4** (Android 5.0.1) and **Alcatel 5033D** (Android 8.1.0) :(

When I used adb commands connecting phone to computer it worked correctly for Samsung:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true
```

In some publics I saw advice in dividing the execution of a line in two stages:

1. `"settings put global airplane_mode_on 1; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true" };`
2. `"settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 && am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true"`
   But it did not help.

Tried another way:

```
String[][] t = new String[][]{new String[] { "su", "settings put global airplane_mode_on 1"},new String[] {"su","am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true" }};
//String[][] t = new String[][]{new String[] { "su", "settings put global airplane_mode_on 1"},new String[] {"am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true" }};
 try {
  Process process = null;
  for (String[] s : t) {
    process  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
  }
  process.waitFor();
}catch (IOException e) {
}catch (SecurityException e){
}catch (Exception e) {
}
```

But it also did not bring a positive result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable/disable airplane mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703088/how-to-enable-disable-airplane-mode)

Comment: SimonC, thanks. Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", "1"); - changes the value in the settings. If you read the settings, it shows what is included. but airplane mode won't start

Answer (score 0):

Without root access, one needs the "default assist app" privilege.
It works for instance with the MacroDroid app - see also https://macrodroidforum.com/wiki/index.php/Action:_Airplane_Mode_On/Off.